# How do I replace a line in a file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to read replace a line in a configuration file using PowerShell. Sometimes this script works, but most of the time it does not replace the line.

```
(Get-Content D:\home\App_Config\Sitecore.config) `
    | %{ $_ -replace '  <setting name="Media.MediaLinkServerUrl" value=" "/>',' <setting name="Media.MediaLinkServerUrl" value="https://newurl.com"/>'} `
    | Set-Content D:\home\App_Config\Sitecore.config
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$file = 'D:\home\App_Config\Sitecore.config'
$regex = '(?<=<setting name="Media\.MediaLinkServerUrl" value=")[^"]*'
(Get-Content $file) -replace $regex, 'https://newurl.com' | Set-Content $file
```

<sup>* Re `Set-Content`: In *Windows PowerShell* it uses your system's legacy single-byte character encoding by default (based on the active ANSI code page), so you may want to use `-Encoding` to control the output file's encoding explicitly; *PowerShell [Core] 6+*  defaults to BOM-less UTF-8.</sup>

- Also note the required `(...)` around the `Get-Content` call to ensure that the pipeline can write back to the same file that `Get-Content` has read from.
- If there's a chance that the opening tag in question (`<setting ...>`) spans *multiple lines*, use
  `Get-Content -Raw $file` (PSv3+) to read the entire file content as a *single string* (thanks, [deadlydog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/602585/deadlydog));
  without `-Raw`, `Get-Content` returns an *array* of strings, representing the input *lines*.

Due to using a regular expression to match your existing setting, *any* text currently inside `value="..."` is matched, so this command will work even when run *repeatedly*.

By contrast, **what you tried** uses an effective *literal* (`... value=" "`) to find what to replace, and after the 1st - successful - run, that literal no longer matches, and subsequent runs have no effect.

The command above uses a streamlined approach to replacement:

- `(?<=<setting name="Media.MediaLinkServerUrl" value=")` is a look-behind assertion (`(?<=...)`) that matches, but doesn't capture what it matches: it finds the part up to and including the opening `"` of the value you're trying to replaces, without making that prefix a part of what will get replaced.
- `[^"]*` then matches the entire value, up to, but not including the closing `"`. (`[^"]` is a character set that matches any character *other* than (`^`) a `"`, and `*` finds any (possibly empty) sequence of such characters.
- Therefore, because the regex captured only the value itself, all you need to specify as the replacement string is the new value.

Answer (score 26):

Use the Replace method like this:

```
$file = 'D:\home\App_Config\Sitecore.config'
$find = '  <setting name="Media.MediaLinkServerUrl" value=" "/>'
$replace = ' <setting name="Media.MediaLinkServerUrl" value="https://newurl.com"/>'

(Get-Content $file).replace($find, $replace) | Set-Content $file
```

Comment: `.Replace()` is a _method_ of .NET type `[string]`, not an _operator_. Unlike PowerShell's `-replace` operator, which uses regular expressions, `.Replace()` performs _literal_ substring replacements, which I suspect may be neha's problem: after an initial (successful) run of the script, the literal doesn't match anymore.

Comment: To put it differently: Even though your code is more concise and more efficient, it is in essence the same as the OP's and doesn't explain the intermittent failures.
(The only - negligible - functional difference is that the `.` in the search string in the OP's command, due to use of `-replace`, is the match-any-character regex metacharacter, whereas it is a literal in your command, as it should be.)

Comment: code provide by me some time works perfectlly but sometime even though search string is :  <setting name="Media.MediaLinkServerUrl" value=" "/> still it is not replacing it. I will try your script but confused why mine is not working !

Comment: @mklement0 's answer is better than mine, he knows the dark art of regex. I missed that class in wizarding school ;)

Comment: Thanks, James. @neha: I assume you're running your code repeatedly on the same file, trying to update the `value="..."` part every time, correct? However, your code only finds a value that is _literally_ `value=" "`, which means that if your file originally contained this value, you'll replace it with `value="https://newurl.com"` on the _first_ run. After that, trying to update the value again will invariably fail, because _literal_ `value=" "` can no longer be found.

Comment: @mklement no this is not the case...I am manually changing value ="newurl" to value=" " everytime before running script. But still facing the issue..Anyway will work with the script given by you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

## This Function worked for me

I am trying to replace anything come after Infile 
[image]

## Function:

```
function Write-FileContent {
        [cmdletBinding()]
        param(
            [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [string]$FileToReplacePath,
            [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [string]$TextToReplaceWith,
            [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [string]$LineNumber,
            [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [string]$TextToBeingWith        
        )
        $Read = Get-Content -Path $FileToReplacePath
        $Read | ForEach-Object { if ($_.ReadCount -eq $LineNumber) { $_ -replace "'$TextToBeginWith'=.+'", "$TextToReplaceWith" }   else { $_ } } | Set-Content $FileToReplacePath
    }
```

## Testing Parameter

```
$CsvFilePath="C:\msydatfgdfa.csv"
Write-FileContent -FileToReplacePath D:\test.txt -TextToReplaceWith "'$CsvFilePath'" -LineNumber 2 -TextToBeingWith "Infile"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that preserves the PSPath property, so you don't have to specify the path to set-content:

```
(Get-Content -raw input) | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace 111,222 |
    Add-Member NoteProperty PSPath $_.PSPath -PassThru
} | Set-Content -nonewline
```