# Powershell, how to exclude the "\" character in a Regex format

Tags: regex, powershell, match, character, reserved

Based to this Topic: [How do I replace a line in a file using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679169/how-do-i-replace-a-line-in-a-file-using-powershell)

```
<setting name="Media.MediaLinkServerUrl" value=" "/>
```

The Regex to select whatever inside: value=" and "/> is

```
$regex = '(?<=<setting name="Media\.MediaLinkServerUrl" value=")[^"]*'
```

It work well!

but what about if:

```
<setting name="Media.MediaLinkServerUrl" value=" \/>
```

I tried:

```
$regex = '(?<=<setting name="Media\.MediaLinkServerUrl" value=")[^\]*'
```

and

```
$regex = '(?<=<setting name="Media\.MediaLinkServerUrl" value=")[^\\]*'
```

but it doesn't work!

I know `\` is an reserved regex character, but `[^.]*` or `[^|]*` for example work well.

So how to select between `\` and `\` with Regex in Powershell in the example above?

A Big thx!

Ps: I can't comment or ask on the original post because i don't have 50 reputation, sorry.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What's the expected outcome?

Comment: Your `[^\\]*` example does work and will match the space between `"` and ``\``. aside from that, its not clear what the intent is

Comment: `value="` isn't a valid attribute, because a closing `"` is missing.

Comment: Thx to Santiago Squarzon and mklement0 for your answers, you helped me to find the problem!